# C# multiple serial ports simultanious reading

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

back again with another serial port question.

Over the past two weeks I have been refining my code to try and read off of two serial devices. Currently, the program gets **almost** all of the data (about 99% compared to the 50% I had before) but I am still missing data.

Here is my "Main" function:

```
private Program()
    {
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        port2.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port2_DataReceived);


        port.Open();
        port2.Open();


        Application.Run();
    }
```

Here is the code I am using for both serial ports:

```
public void port1IntoBuffer()
    {
        int messageLength = 96; 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[messageLength];
        port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, messageLength);

        for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++)
        {
            if ((int)buffer[i] <= 48 && (int)buffer[i] > 0)
            {
                tickQ.Enqueue((new IdDate { Id = (int)buffer[i], Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") }));
            }
        }
        if (!Locked)
        {
            Locked = true;
            Thread readThread = new Thread(() => submitSQL());
            readThread.Start();
        }
    }
```

I have this code duplicated for port two as well. The messageLength is just an arbitrary number for testing. As for my input, I am expecting an integer value between 1-48. The tickQ variable is a ConcurrentQueue that I have both ports enqueued onto (it is later dequeued and sent to a SQL DB).

If anybody could give me some hints as to what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Thank you!

EDIT 1:

After reading BlueStrat's suggestion, I have changed my sql submit code to the following:

```
public void submitSQL()
    {
        lock (Locked)
        {
            int retryCount = 3;
            bool success = false;
            while (retryCount > 0 && !success)
            {
                try
                {



                    IdDate tempData;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {

                        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxxxx;" +
                                                "Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;" +
                                                "User id=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxx; Connection Timeout=0";

                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO XXXXX (submitTime, machineID) VALUES (@submitTIME, @machineId)";

                        cmd.Connection = con;


                        con.Open();
                        while (tickQ.TryDequeue(out tempData))
                        {


                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineId", (tempData.Id));
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@submitTIME", tempData.Date);

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        con.Close();



                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    retryCount--;
                }
                finally
                {
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is after 10 minutes, my RAM usage for this program explodes (grows from about 6MB to 150MB) and then the program crashes.

EDIT 2: With everybody's recommendations, the results have improved! I only missed about 8 out of ~15,000 transmission last night. I'm going to try increasing my serial read buffer to hopefully catch more transmissions.

Comment: you could elaborate on what the expected data is and what it is you are currently getting?

Comment: My expected data is an integer value between 1-48, and I record when the value was received (with my DateTime.Now()). Once I have two data points of the same integer value, I subtract the arrival times to get a duration. My problem is occasional I will miss a transition, making my duration much longer than it should be.

Comment: Hmmmm - considering the above code seems to be perfectly solid and you get 99% of the expected data, I kind of want to stab at the idea that the issue is not in C# and is related to whatever is generating the data or the channel through which the data is sent (for example, if it's goes over an RF connection at some point, maybe some of the data is not received by the receiver).  do you have any way to verify that all of the data points are indeed coming over the serial connection?

Comment: I am comparing my results with the already in place system (the program I am writing is going to replace it). My program is usually off by 5 or 6 reads (meaning, the old program gets 500 reads but mine only gets 495). I would try and copy the code from this old VB program, but it is using MSCommLib and I really do not want to use that.

Comment: Could it be that the amount you are reading into the buffer is running long and clipping off a few bytes from the next message?  Do you have any kind of terminator you can read until instead?

Comment: That could be, I'll try and shrink my buffer size. Annoyingly I usually cannot tell if the changes I made work until after a couple of hours (because missed data is so inconsistent and rare). Sadly, this serial device just streams numbers, no delimiting characters or anything.

Comment: Yeah that sounds really frustrating to test.  If it's just streaming numbers though you might be better just reading the size of the number being sent (16/32/64/128 bytes, depending on what size the source is)

Comment: Ah that is a good idea. I will try that for testing. Thank you for your help thus far!

Comment: `ReadAsync()` will return early while the data is being fetched from the port.  I think you should probably `await` for completion of the Task or schedule a continuation in the returned Task so you can begin processing the data once it is fully read. Or better, switch to the non-async version `Read()`

Comment: I was previously using just Read(), but I wasn't getting all the data either. I also read in this blog-post: http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport that ReadAsync is preferable to Read(). I did add the await and async though, thank you for catching that.

Comment: @J.Boyer: If the only "delimiter" is a somewhat longer pause between characters, rather than actually transmitting a newline or comma or such, then this is really hard to do without control over the port advanced timeout settings.  In native code (`SetCommTimeouts()`) it's possible to use a fairly large value for `ReadTotalTimeoutConstant` and then a small `ReadIntervalTimeout`.  Unfortunately the .NET layer `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` on top doesn't allow you to change these independently, you will have to p/invoke.

Comment: If you do have fixed-width values, then use the number of characters received to determine whether you need to split one read buffer into multiple values.

Comment: @J.Boyer, I understand you began to experience excessive memory usage after the suggested change to a real `lock()` statement?   Are you locking over the same member in a different part of the code?

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you for your suggestions! I do have fixed-width values so I should be able to split my read buffer.

Comment: @BlueStrat I am just calling the lock() statement inside of my submitSQL() function. This helped alot, but my RAM usage still grew last night (from about 6mb to 14mb). I think I need to increase my buffer read so more data gets sent in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues I notice in your code, the first one I addressed as a comment. **The `'ReadAsync()'` function call is asynchronous, meaning it will return early, while the requested data is fetched in the background.**

Normally you would handle this by issuing an `await` on the returned `Task`, signalling that you want the code to resume (without blocking the current thread) once the requested amount of bytes have been fully read.

`await` is only available since C# 5.  If you are running on a lower version, then you typically schedule a continuation, which is a kind of delegate that will run AFTER the Task is complete. However, I think that simply switching to the `Read()` version would be fine, the thread will certainly block while waiting for the data, but at least you are certain that you have read the expected amount of bytes.

**The other issue I notice is your locking code that is relying on a boolean flag, it is not thread-safe**.  The issue is that the code that checks the status of the `Lock` flag  to conditionally enter the guarded block and the code that actually sets the status of the flag inside the block is not atomic.  **This means that a different thread could enter the code you are trying to protect while another thread has also entered the same code block, but still hasn't managed to switch the guard flag to true**, in this case, both threads will run the same code and probably produce an unexpected result  (not sure if this possibility has something to do with your missing data problem).

I can't really recommend how to rewrite your lock-guard code without viewing how else the `Lock` member is used and how it is released. If you post the rest of the code snippets interacting with the `Lock` member I may be able to offer some advice.

**EDIT: (more information after OP's comment)**

> The purpose of that flag was to prevent every thread from posting to
>   the database at once (I kept getting deadlock errors, but I don't
>   think that would cause my data loss).

**With that bit of information I think that you might have another problem that could certainly explain missing data.  What happens if Flag is true? you simply skip launching the thread that submits data to your SQL server, you never retry, <s>so the buffered data is lost once the method exits</s>.**   Sorry, you won't lose data because you are enqueing it, what you might lose is the necessary amount of thread launches to actually drain the data reception queue.  When you experience the data loss, check your `tickQ` queue, I bet that it will still have data to process, because the thread that should have dealt with it was never started for the same reasons.

Adding a `lock()` statement inside the `submitSQL()` function will protect you from that possibility.

Remove the Locked member completely from you code and try this:

```
// Add this member to your class;
object SqlLock = new object();



    void submitSQL() {
      // add this at the start of your submitSQL() method
       lock (SqlLock ) {
         ... the rest of your code
       }
    }
```

The difference with your current code is that if the SQL instance is in use by another thread, the calling thread will **block AND WAIT** for it to be available before continuing, instead of simply <s>discarding the data that has just been read.</s> not launching the thread that handles the en-queued data.

**EDIT: Final piece of advice**

**I would encourage you to refrain from creating a new thread every time you need to drain your queue**, instead you can rely on the thread pool (See `Task.Run()`). Using a thread from the pool removes the expensive overhead of manually creating threads.

Another possibility is to create a single thread that will be continuously dedicated to draining the data queue. You can use an `AutoResetEvent` in order to coordinate work between the producer thread (the thread that enqueues) and the consumer thread (the thread that dequeues)  Your consumer thread enters a loop that calls `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()`, where it will block; your producer thread enqueues received data and instead of spawning a new thread, it calls `AutoResetEvent.Set()` causing the consumer thread to wake-up and handle the enqueued data, once it is handled, it blocks again, waiting for the next data batch to arrive.  If you do so, make sure you mark your thread as a `BackgroundThread`, so it doesn't prevent the application from shutting down if the thread is waiting for data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my non-threadsafe boolean flag, I didn't even think about that not being thread safe. The purpose of that flag was to prevent every thread from posting to the database at once (I kept getting deadlock errors, but I don't think that would cause my data loss). I also did change from asyncread to read (the AsyncRead started slowing down alot, it was taking 10+ minutes for data to get to the database).

Comment: Thanks for all your help BlueStart, I have changed from a boolean value to a lock. If you have time, please refer to my edit in the OP which contains an updated version of my submitSQL function.

Comment: There is a minor issue in your `submitSQL()` function. The `success=true;` statement shouldn't be inside your `finally` block. It should be after  
`con.Close()`. Otherwise you will never retry, since the finally block (where you signal success) will run even when you catch an exception.

Comment: Viewing your full submitSQL() implementation, I think that your experienced data losses happened if you happened to receive a final batch of data, just after the while() block that is draining the queue had exited, but before you cleared the Locked flag,  this would cause your original code to never schedule the thread that drains the final piece of data. Hope this all helps!

Comment: Thank you very much BlueStrat! I'll let these changes run over night and see if it helps with the data loss. Fingers crossed!